# Advice on Developing With Classic ASP in 2011

Tags: asp-classic

I have been tasked with fixing bugs and adding new features to a website written in Classic ASP that basically hasn't been touched by a developer in 8 years. I last worked with ASP about 10 years ago myself, so to say the least, I am not looking forward to having to dive back into the inevitable spaghetti code.

What tools and resources are recommended to use today for working with Classic ASP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The good thing is that **Classic ASP** didn't change in the last 10 years as well :)

So all you knew back then, you still know now!

Every time I want to change an old website made in ASP, i end up using a trial version of **[Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html)** (though I hate it now, but it has **auto-completion** of ASP code, witch sometimes can be handy), but I always go with **[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download)**

I always set up the **IIS** and point the **Virtual Directory** to the folder I'm working on, and just code.

If you want a more heavy solution, run **Visual Studio** there are severalarticles on [how to configure an Classic ASP solution to debug it](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/DebugVBScriptVS2008.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

.Net COM visible objects are available to classic asp...

eg:

```
Set al = CreateObject( "System.Collections.ArrayList" )
```

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29496334/dotnet-in-vbscript.aspx

Maybe helpful?

Comment: Very interesting. This could definitely be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Find an editor that works with Classic ASP. I personally use gvim, but if you are not familiar with VI, then i would  suggest going through the trouble of getting Visual Studio to debug level. This is fine for 2005/2008, there are resources on how to do it. Depending on which OS you are running on you might have some quirks with getting classic ASP running through IIS. (Windows 7 gave me some hickups in getting it started but was fine once it was running)

When maintaining an existing site I would highly suggest trying to make your DEV environment mirror your PROD environment as closely as possible regarding the root of the website/application.

If the ASP classic application has some unit testing already, great. If not, adding it for anything new that you add insight into what you break when you change things. [ASP Unit](http://aspunit.sourceforge.net/) helps with this (does not appear to be maintained, but functional). Also building front end experience tests with [Watin](http://watin.org/) helps.

If there is no documentation, start some.

Depending on what your time budget is like, if there will be lots of maintenance in the future it might be useful to start adding some structure to your spaghetti mess where possible. There are some useful frameworks that can be put in place: [AXE (Asp Xtreme Evolution)](http://zend.lojcomm.com.br/goodies/asp-xtreme-evolution/) is a workable MVC framework for ASP Classic, and comes with a large library of utility code that make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

I love [this](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/index.shtml) DHTML components when I was working in Classic asp.